# Fetch data from .db file

Tags: database, flutter, dart

How can I **ONLY** fetch data from database but not create database or some these things? I didn't found tutorial, that shows how to fetch data only.
For example, I have in database name (key) "Support" and next to text "Contact support" so how I can retrieve text "Contact support" with key "Support"?
Please as simple as possible.

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of database.  There are dozens!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz SQL database

Comment: Your description is vague. If you have a DB filetype, it is possible you are dealing a SQLite file. If so, you can use `sqlite3` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite3), but you need to know SQL language to fetch data from it.

Comment: Yeah, SQL only rules out the no-SQL databases, so we're down to half-dozens. :)

Comment: Please help me :D I have just .db file man